# .htacess rewrite from folder breaks the website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a rewrite rule so if a visitor types:
https://mywebsite.com/app/invite/abc123
it gets parsed as:
https://mywebsite/invite.php?id=abc123

using the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^app/invite/(.+)$ /app/invite.php?id=$1
```

The issue is that all relative links break after rewriting, as the **invite** is not a real existing directory and it is added to all relative links.

How can I fix this or prevent adding the invite directory to links?

---

I wanted to point out that I use the following rules in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect http  to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove php file extension from links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I am trying to adjust all they do not result in infinite redirects or interval server errors.

I use **Apache/2.4.46**.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this issue by using this code:

```
RewriteRule "^app/invite/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)" "/app/invite?id=$1" [NC,L,QSA]
```

and in the invite.php I set the base in the `<head>` tag to:

```
<base href="../">
```

So it jump back to the actual directory and don't break the website links.
If any one has a better approach, I will be delighted if they share with me.
Cheers!